# Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'> while reshaping

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to build a convolutional variational autoencoder. For that purpose, I need to flatten and unflatten the tensor. But while I am trying to store the shape prior to flattening it (for reshaping it back in decoder part), I am encountering the following error

```
Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'\>
```

while trying to reshape the tensor. I am including the code and error below.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from  tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
%matplotlib inline

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('./MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
input_shape = [28, 28]
def encoder(_input):
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(_input, 3, [5,5], strides=(2,2), activation=tf.nn.elu)
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, 6, [5,5], strides=(2, 2), activation=tf.nn.elu)
    logits = tf.layers.conv2d(conv2, 2, [3, 3], activation=None)
    flat = tf.layers.flatten(logits)

    return flat

def decoder(flat):
    shape = flat.get_shape().as_list()
    return shape

x_train = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 28, 28, 1])

enc = encoder(x_train)
dec = decoder(enc)

img = np.reshape(mnist.train.images[:2], (-1, 28, 28, 1))
img.shape

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    val = sess.run(dec, feed_dict={x_train: img})
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-5f497519723a> in <module>()
      3 with tf.Session() as sess:
      4     sess.run(init)
----> 5     summary, val = sess.run([summary_op, dec], feed_dict={x_train: img})
      6 

/home/13mcpc11/anaconda2/envs/dl-py2-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    887     try:
    888       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 889                          run_metadata_ptr)
    890       if run_metadata:
    891         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/home/13mcpc11/anaconda2/envs/dl-py2-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1103     # Create a fetch handler to take care of the structure of fetches.
   1104     fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(
-> 1105         self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
   1106 
   1107     # Run request and get response.

/home/13mcpc11/anaconda2/envs/dl-py2-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in __init__(self, graph, fetches, feeds, feed_handles)
    412     """
    413     with graph.as_default():
--> 414       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
    415     self._fetches = []
    416     self._targets = []

/home/13mcpc11/anaconda2/envs/dl-py2-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in for_fetch(fetch)
    232     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
    233       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.
--> 234       return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
    235     elif isinstance(fetch, dict):
    236       return _DictFetchMapper(fetch)

/home/13mcpc11/anaconda2/envs/dl-py2-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in __init__(self, fetches)
    339     """
    340     self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
--> 341     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
    342     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
    343 

/home/13mcpc11/anaconda2/envs/dl-py2-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in for_fetch(fetch)
    229     if fetch is None:
    230       raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r' %
--> 231                       (fetch, type(fetch)))
    232     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
    233       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.

TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>
```